# Mod Rewriting - really stuck

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

The site I'm talking about is a subdirectory of my main site. `site/index` redirects to `index.php`. `site/gallery` redirects to `gallery.php`. Now, I'd like `site/gallery/question/answer` to link to `site/gallery.php?question=answer`. `question` can have two possible values, `answer` can have several hundred.

Because it's `site/gallery` (without an end slash), `site/gallery/question/answer` doesn't load properly. And when I do rewrite it so it does work (with the end slash), I have to re-do all of my images and links in my HTML and CSS parts to work with that, because else it'd redirect to the main site (because of the additional slash). Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^gallery/(q1|q2)/([-A-Za-z0-9=_]+)$ index.php?$1=$2 [L,NC,NE,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^gallery$ gallery.php [L,NC,NE,QSA]
```

Attached index.php

```
<?php
print_r($_GET); 
die();
```

Comment: /gallery/answer/question was not found on this server.

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^gallery/(q1|q2)/([-A-Za-z0-9=_]+) gallery.php?$1=$2 [L,NC,NE,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^gallery$ gallery.php [L,NC,NE,QSA]

UGH, why won't proper formatting work. <_<

Comment: The sample url would be something like [link](http://example.com/gallery/q1/any_answer_here) Where q1 or q2 are the 2 possible questions and any_answer_here are any of the answers from your original post. Updated my answer to reflect what you posted and added index.php for test.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks a bunch, works perfectly! Is there anything I can do apart from your answer solved it? Rep, karma, whatever?